# geninfo searches .da instead of .gcda

Tags: command, code-coverage, putty, plink, lcov

When I try to execute the following lcov command through Plink (I give Plink a text file as an argument containing the following command)

```
lcov --capture --directory . --output-file coverage.info
```

it results with

> GNU gcov version 1.5 Capturing coverage data from .
>   **Scanning . for .da files ...** gcov [-b] [-v] [-n] [-l] [-f] [-o OBJDIR] file geninfo: Use of uninitialized value in pattern match
>   (m//) at /home/myUser/lcov/lcov/usr/bin/geninfo line 1874. gcov [-b]
>   [-v] [-n] [-l] [-f] [-o OBJDIR] file geninfo: Use of uninitialized
>   value in pattern match (m//) at /home/myUser/lcov/lcov/usr/bin/geninfo
>   line 3622. geninfo: Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)
>   at /home/myUser/lcov/lcov/usr/bin/geninfo line 3622.
>   **geninfo: ERROR: no .da files found in .!**

It seems that the geninfo expects for *.da* files instead of *.gcda* files.
when I execute the same command without Plink (in the same CWD), the lcov runs fine and generates a valid *.info* file. It also runs fine when I execute it manually thorugh PuTTY.

what might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was more general. Plink uses **different environment variables**. The solution was to set manually the correct environment variables. In my case I run perl script so I added in the head of the file:

```
use Env;
$ENV{PATH} = "correct PATH variable";
```

a missing environment variable caused the code to get wrong gcov version and therefore .da files were serached instead of .gcda files that belong to newer lcov versions

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading lcov version to latest solved the issue. Older version of lcov searches .da instead of .gcda. Updating to latest version 1.13 solves the issue